# Retrieve a table value from a JList

Tags: java, data-binding, netbeans, jlist

(NetBeans 7.2.1 )

I have created a `JList` `Employees_List` and binded it as below:

```
Bind elements:
    Binding source = tblEmployeesList
    Binding Expression = null
    Display Expression = ${empLName}, ${empFName} ${empMName}
Bind selectedElement:
    Binding source = tblEmployeesList
    Binding Expression = ${EmpID}
```

How do I retrieve the value of `EmpID` from the table `tblEmployeesList` when an item in the list is selected?  (I do not want the `EmpID` displayed in the list.)

I attempted the following:

```
String strEmpID;
strEmpID = Employees_List.getSelectedValue().toString();
```

which returns the selected value in the list box.  However, I need to obtain the `EmpID` which I binded to the selectedElement.  I find nothing similar to `.getselectedElement` for the list.